# Regenerate Storage Account key using an Arm Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-blob-storage

I would like to regenerate storage key via arm template, in documents it is specified manually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account#regenerate-storage-access-keys. Is there a way to force generate via arm template if it already exists.

Comment: I don't think it is possible through ARM template. But you can manage your access key through key vault. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys

Comment: How about using REST API to do it? ARM template essentially transfer the api.

Comment: ok, if not via template I am looking to do it via c#, is it possible to do via IResourceManagementClient. @Thomas you have pointed me to manage via key vault, do we know if there is a way to regenerate it via c#, in the document I see that there a property to regenerate periodically set via powershell commands

Comment: or may be is there a equivalent to this Update-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccountKey or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/regeneratekey in c#